# How to create a view with contextual filters and then make menus to filter it?

Tags: panels, views

I have created a content type that I want to list and filter on taxonomy terms. 
For example I want to show all posts of that content type on the frontpage. Then I want to be able to create menu items with name of all the existing taxonomy terms I have to choose from. Then i want those terms to link to a page with the filtered content for only that term.

I can create this by making a new view for every taxonomy term but it must be a better way to do this since if I have around 40 terms it's gonna get really messy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out. With help from this tutorial http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views and the reason why the links in the menus dind't work for me were because I was using the same url as the taxonomy term had so I only got a term list. So I just changed the view url to something else than the taxonomy and it worked.

It now works if I write the view adress/any termreference without having to create a separate view for all of them.